# Ios create pdf from array of byte

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf

i want create a pdf from a stream of byte (that i receive from a wsdl), i have insert this stream of byte on NSArray but i don't know how write the pdf.
(This stream of byte is a pdf)
Thanks!

```
                //to convert NSData to pdf
                NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrayOfByte];

                CFDataRef myPDFData  = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)data;
                CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(myPDFData);
                CGPDFDocumentRef pdf   = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);

                NSArray *docDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *docDirectory = [docDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *fileName = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abcd.pdf"];

                [data writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO];
```

But i receive:  failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.

Comment: What do you mean by create a PDF?, isn't what you are receiving a PDF already?

Comment: yes but i want create pdf into iphone ipad , sorry i have forgot this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the bytes of data from your array of signed 8-bit characters, you could do something like:

```
NSArray *bytes = ...;

NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:bytes.count];
for (NSNumber *byteVal in bytes) {
    Byte b = (Byte)(byteVal.intValue);
    [data appendBytes:&b length:1];
}
```

This should work, but it would be more efficient if you populated the `data` object directly when you're parsing the JSON.

Then you can write the bytes to a file using:

```
NSArray *docDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDirectory = [docDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abcd.pdf"];

[data writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO];
```

Comment: Hi tnks for the response. i have make :                      CFDataRef myPDFData  = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)data;
CGDataProviderRef provider =CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(myPDFData);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf= CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);
NSArray*docDirectories=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDirectory = [docDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abcd.pdf"];
[data writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO];
but i receive: failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.

Comment: I don't think you want to use [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrayOfByte]. That assumes that arrayOfByte is a binary plist.

Did the data come to you in that NSArray?
If so, of what type are the items inside the array?
if not, what was the original form of the data in the WSDL reply?

Comment: TNKS, i receive the byte from wsdl in this form:                 {"byte":["37","80","68","70","45","49","46","52","10","37","-30","-29","-49","45","10","49","32","48","32","111","98","106","10","60","60","47","84","121","112","101","47","88","79","98","106","101","99","116","47"]} this is only a little part of the response. And i parse the json into a NSArray that contains all the byte.

Comment: NSArray *parts = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *previewDocumentFileName = [parts lastObject]; previewDocumentFileName contains the data(pdf content) that needs to be copied in to pdf.I followed your solution,but it doesn't seem to work.Raises issue "Unable to open pdf because it's not valid pdf"

Answer (score 0):

If it really is a byte array, it should either be encoded as a string and turned into an `NSData` object, or stored directly in an `NSData` object.  From there, CoreGraphics includes native functions to create and manipulate PDF files.

```
//to convert NSData to pdf
NSData *data     = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void)wdslBytes length:sizeOf(wdslBytes)];
CFDataRef myPDFData  = (CFDataRef)data;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(myPDFData);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf   = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);
```

Comment: hi tnks for the response. i have make this NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array]; and how use CGPDFDocumentRef for create pdf?

Comment: What?  I just showed you how.  And you aren't receiving a byte array, PDF data is much bigger than that.

Comment: I receive 9830 byte from wsdl, and i have insert this byte on array. But i don't understand how can write a file.pdf with your code. thanks for the help.